# Import error running unittest in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a problem importing files in Python 3.6. My directories tree is as given below:

```
project/
    app/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py
    test/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_a.py
    └── test_b.py
```

It works my application (but, no works the tests) using following import statement in `b.py`:

```
from a import *
```

But, it does not work my application (but, works the tests) using this other in `b.py`:

```
from .a import *
```

So, I choose `from a import *`. Executing test like `python3 -m unittest` I always get following error:

```
E.
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.test_cell (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_cell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/serrodcal/Repositories/project/tests/test_b.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app.b import *
  File "/Users/serrodcal/Repositories/project/app/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

In this case, my import statement in `test_b.py` is as given below:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from app.cell import *
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post the content of you \_\_init\_\_.py?

Comment: I think it's easier for you to share the [repository](https://github.com/MULCIA/TFMSTGCA). There you can see all the information because in this post I do not pretend to show my specific case.

Comment: Regarding your question, `__init__.py` is empty, like many example that I could see.

Comment: psst, please check out `pytest`, it resembles idiomatic Python rather than re-using Java patterns and there's a fat chance you'll enjoy it much more

Comment: Yep, that is more Pythonic but unittest is included and I do not want to import more libraries.

Comment: \_\_init\_\_.py is not needed in Python 3.3+ unless needing to run an installation script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was confused with imports in Python and how python works with modules.

```
project/
    module/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
    test/
        test_a.py
        test_b.py
    main.py
```

This is my new directories tree. The contains of the files are:

In `main.py`:

```
from module.b import Something
```

In `b.py`:

```
from .a import Something
```

In `a.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from module.a import Something
```

In `test_b.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from module.a import Something
from module.b import Something
```

Like this, it works fine, application and tests.

Comment: Why should the structure be like this?

Comment: I think you wanted to say: 'In test_a.py' instead of 'In a.py'.

Comment: It is also important to mention that 'module' must be installed in site-packages. Otherwise, you will have to add it to sys.path.