# Error importing with unittest and Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am developing a small project using Python 3.6 version. Implementing the unit test with unittest I have an error executing `python3 -m unittest` and I have not an error executing `python -m unittest`.

The error shows import error like:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'genome'
```

Is there any import problem using unittest in Python 3.6?

Comment: Complete information about this error and the solution is post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44324806/4436650).

Answer (score 1):

You probably call two different versions of Python, that do not have the same packages installed.

It seems that `genome` is not installed with `python3`. If `genome` is an Internet installed package, you can fix this with

```
python3 -m pip install genome
```

Answer (score 0):

You can found the unittest module introduce document from https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Comment: How this gonna solve the error mentionned previously?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without you showing your code, but to add to Guillaume's answer, the syntax for relative imports is different between python2 and python3

In python3, The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is `from .[module] import name`. All import forms not starting with . are interpreted as absolute imports.

See [(PEP 0328)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more information

Comment: I read that links previously, and others, like saul comment. I do not understand the problem. As I posted yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315077/import-error-running-unittest-in-python3), from .module import * must work, but It does not work. I guess it's a subtle mistake.

Comment: So how are we supposed to link tests in a sister directory ( ../other )? I am working within a multi-language framework with the convention that each package has ONLY sub-directories, all predefined, and two of them being `SRC/` and `TEST/`. The only option available for storing tests is (relative to source under test) `../TEST/test_[some_source]`. Is there no way to make this work with `unittest` module?